# just learning the terms of sql and eror had just popped out

Tags: sql, group-by, compiler-errors, sql-order-by

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYapf.png)

```
SELECT student_id from student GROUP BY Marks ORDER BY DESC
```

i had just run these query but getting error can anyone please explain me what the sceneario?

i was just trying two operation such as order and group

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Grouping without aggregation doesn't make sense. Do you want the *quantity* of students that scored each mark? Something else? Please add more information and provide the schema for the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `SELECT` something that is also in your `GROUP BY`. Anything in the `SELECT` part which is not in your `GROUP BY` needs to be inside an aggregate function, e.g. `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, `AVG` etc. You could try something like

```
SELECT student_id, MAX(Marks), MIN(Marks)
FROM student
GROUP BY student_id
ORDER BY student_id DESC
```